# Holt Winters Model Failing with Error "Optimization Failure" in R

Tags: r, dataframe, statsmodels, forecasting, holtwinters

I was trying to forecast a model using holt winters in R and this failed as showing the below mentioned error. I am not sure what is the issue and how to bypass it? I am actually forecasting this on loop so, because of this error my other time series forecasts with other SKU's are not getting completed.

Can someone help me out with this. Please

[image]

Attached is the dataset which is used and the code which I ran for the same.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyr)
library(tidymodels)
library(forecast)
library(prophet)
library(readxl)
pd1 <- readxl::read_excel("C:X/X/X")
colnames(pd1)[1]="X1"
Y1 = ts(data = pd1$X1,
        frequency = 12,
        start = c(2019,1),
        end = c(2022,8))

training_Y1 = window(x=Y1,
                  end = c(2022,8))

Model_Y1 = HoltWinters(x=training_Y1,
                       seasonal = "additive")
```

The data frame pd1 is given below:

```
structure(list(X1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 38, 7, 7, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -44L), class = "data.frame")
```